# Subquery and normal query comes out with different results

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a beginner of the oracle, currently, I'm doing a question using subquery(without JOIN) and normal (with JOIN) query, but at the end, the results are different from this two query,
I can't figure out this problem, does anyone know?

The question is asking about list the dog owner details which has booked at least twice in this platform

```
SELECT PET_OWNER.Owner_id,Oname,OAdd,COUNT(*) AS BOOKING 
FROM PET_OWNER 
WHERE Owner_id IN(
  SELECT Owner_id 
  FROM PET 
  WHERE PType = 'DOG' AND Pet_id IN(SELECT Pet_id FROM BOOKING))
GROUP BY PET_OWNER.Owner_id,Oname,OAdd
HAVING COUNT(*) >=2
ORDER BY PET_OWNER.Owner_id;
```

This subquery shows no rows selected,

```
SELECT PET_OWNER.Owner_id,Oname,OAdd,COUNT(*) AS BOOKING 
FROM PET_OWNER,PET,BOOKING 
WHERE PET_OWNER.Owner_id = PET.Owner_id AND 
  PET.Pet_id = BOOKING.Pet_id AND 
  PType = 'DOG'
GROUP BY PET_OWNER.Owner_id,Oname,OAdd
HAVING COUNT(*) >=2
ORDER BY PET_OWNER.Owner_id;
```

this query shows 10 records which are the correct answer for this question

I expected these two queries come out with the same result but it is not
does anyone know what is wrong with it?

can anyone show me how to convert this code to subquery?

Comment: Where is the second query?

Answer (score 0):

What happen is that it will give you distinct values on your `PET_OWNER.Owner_id,Oname,OAdd`. So what we need is to `group by owner_id` first.

Here's your query. get first those `owner_id` with `count() >= 2` as `subquery`

```
select * from Pet_Owner where Owner_id in (
    select t1.Owner_id from PET_OWNER t1
    inner join PET t2 on t1.Owner_id = t2.Owner_id
    inner join Booking t3 on t3.Pet_id = t2.Pet_id
    where pType = 'DOG'
    group by t1.Owner_id
    having count(1) >= 2)
order by Owner_id
```

**not using join**, `nested subqueries` is our only option

```
select * from Pet_Owner where Owner_id in (
    select owner_id from Pet_Owner where Owner_id in 
        (select Owner_id from Pet where Pet_id in 
            (select Pet_id in Booking) and PType='DOG')
    group by owner_id
    having count(1) >= 2)
order by Owner_id
```

if you are trying to the `# of dogs` per owner:

```
select * from Pet_Owner where Owner_id in (
    select Owner_id from Pet where Pet_id in 
        (select Pet_id in Booking) and PType='DOG'
    group by owner_id
    having count(1) >= 2)
) order by Owner_id
```

Comment: if i dont use inner join,any alternative ways?

Comment: you are relating multiple tables, the way your query joins the tables is the old fashion way, existed 10 yrs ago

Comment: she ask me to do subquery without any joins

Comment: @metal still the same as my earlier subquery results

Comment: @fayelan, what do you mean? i seems 'dog' needs to be 'DOG'

Comment: yeah, PType ='DOG'

Comment: but still no records found

Comment: you need to share your sample data

Comment: how? my data script has 200+rows

Comment: @metal i know whats the problem,i think should group by pet_id instead of group by owner_id

Comment: well, you are asking for # of owners not number of dogs

Comment: im asking which dog owners has booking at least twice, but Pet_id is the foreign key in table Booking

Comment: try my 3rd query

Comment: now only have 1 records, the correct answer should have 10 records same as my normal query

Answer (score 0):

Because duplicated join key will cause duplicatation in result.
In your case, the Owner_id should be non-unique in the PET table.
It is still possible to get the correct answer by using join. And as the owner_id in the subquery t is unique, so the execution plan should be same with the subquery version.

```
select p.* from Pet_Owner p
join (
    select PET.Owner_id 
    from PET
    inner join Booking on Booking.Pet_id = PET.Pet_id
    where pType = 'DOG'
    group by PET.Owner_id
    having count(1) >= 2) t
on t.Owner_id = p.Owner_id 
order by p.Owner_id
```

By the way, your SQL code is so old-school as it is in ANSI-89, while the join syntax is already in ANSI-92. I know many school teachers still love the old style, I hope you can read both, but only write code in ANSI-92 way.

Comment: i know, but im not allowed to use any joins in the subquery

Comment: @faye lan: I hate to break it to your teacher, but the code *IS* a "join".  It just uses an obsolete (and arguably less expressive) syntax.